# Why does a calculator say that 3% + 3% = .0309?

Tags: percentages, calculator

If I use the calculator provided by [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=online%20calculator), I can enter the expression

3% + 3%

and it tells me the answer is 0.0309.  I would think that 3% is the same as .03, which should make the answer .06, no?  Am I misunderstanding what I'm asking of the calculator?

I get the same behavior on my phone's app (of course, it is an Android phone so perhaps shouldn't be surprising).  But on my Windows PC the built in calculator doesn't even let me enter 3% as an operand.  It immediately changes it to zero.

My underlying question is how can 3% + 3% equal .0309?

Comment: That number is the result of incrementing 0.03 by 3%. I agree this is slightly strange behavior.

Comment: Don't trust online calculators by and large. They are not coded especially well, and if they are coded to understand things well, they may have ingrained issues (see: Mathematica/Wolfram Alpha with integrals of highly specialized functions).

Comment: Calculators interpret "$a$ + $b$%" as "add $b$% of $a$ to $a$" so that you can easily work out that, for example, a \$50 item with 10% tax is \$50 + 10% = \$55.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you, your explanation makes the most sense.  I'm just not sure why my question got downvoted.

Comment: Why not include a link to the calculator you used? That seems pretty relevant to me.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor I've updated my post to include a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $3$%  to enlarge on $3$% we'll obtain $0.0309$

because $$0.03\cdot\left(1+\frac{3}{100}\right)=0.0309.$$