# Different results on different calculators

Tags: percentages, calculator

On a casio 991ES plus (or any scientific calculator), 300+100% is equal to 301 but on the mobile calculator app, 300+100% is equal to 600 , why is this ? And is it possible to make the scientific calculator display an answer to that of the mobile calculator app in a way that is not 300+(300×100%).
Thanks

Comment: In the first case, the calculator is not recognizing what you entered. Even today, not all calculators work the same in terms of order of operations when it comes to percentages

Comment: There are different inputs possible: $300\cdot (1+100\%), 300\cdot 200\%$. But at the end you can´t ignore the rules of calculation.

Comment: Bottom line, avoid calculators if you can, and if you can't then learn how it works first.

Comment: Also see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2613027/why-does-a-calculator-say-that-3-3-0309?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper mathematical way to interpret $300+100\%$ is as $300+100\cdot 0.01=300+1=301$.  Multiplication comes before addition.  Scientific calculators usually respect this.  Many "four function with percent" calculators use this syntax for adding tax or markup, so they interpret $300+100\%$ as $300(1+100\cdot 0.01)=600$.  The app on my iphone even does the four function version when the phone is horizontal and all the scientific buttons are displayed.